# Squarespace form not loaded when my jquery runs (in IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

The main problem is square-space builds their forms with java-script (YUI). They have are loading their code on document ready. How can I wait until their form loads? This is only a problem in IE.

My Code: (executes first)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formFieldEl6').each(function(){
        var collection = $.deparam.querystring(window.location);
        $(this).val(collection.id);
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Squarespace Code: (executes last)

```
  var theForm10248992;
  YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
  theForm10248992 = new Squarespace.FormBuilder( "theForm10248992", "formOuterContainer10248992", "formFields10248992", "formAddFieldControl10248992", "formErrorMessage10248992", "formSubmitButton10248992", 10248992,  true ,  false ,  false , "Thanks for responding!" );

  theForm10248992.initializeField( 6, "normal", "Title1", "", true, "", "", 1504386 );
  theForm10248992.initializeField( 9, "normal", "Title2", "", true, "", "", 1504463 );
  theForm10248992.initializeField( 4, "medium", "Title3", "", true, "", "", 1504387 );
  theForm10248992.initializeField( 1, "medium", "Title4", "", true, "", "", 1504395 );
  theForm10248992.initializeField( 2, "large", "Title5", "", true, "", "", 1504390 );
  theForm10248992.initializeField( 1, "small", "Title6", "", true, "", "", 1599975 );

  if (Squarespace.Orderable) { Squarespace.Orderable.ItemManager.initialize(); }
  });
```

The code just fills in a value from the URL and disables the control. This works in FF and Chrome. When debugging with the developer tools in IE, I can manually wait on a breakpoint until the form loads and then the code works, but I still cannot get this to work in a normal setting. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you eaching "$('#formFieldEl6').each(function(){" these are ID tags, you can only have 1 id with that value on the whole document.

Comment: I initially had this loading in the header, and some pages don't have that element. The .each ensured that it would bypass an error if the id didn't exist

Comment: I'm confused. If jQuery doesn't find the element (#formFieldEl6), it doesn't execute the code. So what error is thrown if you don't use .each()?

Comment: Secondly can you show more code and the order in which it is executing.

Comment: IF you are executing your square code last on the document, the jquery on document load is not being dynamicaly called, wrap this $('#formFieldEl6').each(function(){ in a javascript function and call it when your square code has finished running. It is not logical to select elements that do not exist then create them and expect a output :)

Comment: That is my problem, I cannot change the squarespace code and I don't know how to make my code wait to the end without telling it to wait 500 milliseconds or some static time. Obviously, that is not desired.

Comment: use a variable set to 0 on page load, run a setInterval call and in the function set that variable to 1, wrap the setInterval(Function(), 300); around a if statement that says if its 0 run.. it will work that way, wont be very neat though... thats what first comes to mind...

Comment: `$(**window**). **load** (function() { .... }); Fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(window). load (function() { .... }); Fixed the problem – It fires when the entire window has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready()
```

fires when the html and css are loaded. It doesn't check if the images are loaded.

Try 
    $("body").load(function(){alert("body loaded");})

This fires when the html, css and images have loaded, usually it's a little bit later.

Alternately, look into using a timer to run your code a few milliseconds after document.ready fires.